# How do you correctly import react into a node-webkit app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-webkit

I'm trying to create a node-webkit app, and I want to use react.js as my framework. After trying react and creating some components, I tried to use it as follows in a node-webkit app:

```
'use strict';

require('react');
```

Whenever I open my node-webkit app, which includes the above script at the end of the body I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rtol\Dropbox\Code\Node- Webkit\WallpaperManager3.0\node_modules\react\lib\CSSPropertyOperations.js:31:7)
....
```

Am I doing something wrong? All the documentation I've found indicates that this would be the correct way to include react when using node. I have npm installed react, according to package.json it is version 0.13.2.

For instance the [react-nodewebkit](https://github.com/konsumer/react-nodewebkit) starter kit has it's index.jsx as follows.

```
var React = require('react');
var HelloWorld = require('./components/HelloWorld.jsx');

React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

So I can't really figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you installed react on your node modules? `npm install react `?

Comment: Yes, I've also installed other modules and imported them successfully to verify that is was not a problem with require.

Comment: Yep, the problem is not within importing react but document doesn't exist cause you are not running the script on a browser as @insin said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NW.js (which is what node-webkit was renamed to) has two contexts in which scripts can be executed - browser or Node. See [Determining the context of a script](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts#determining-thecontext-ofascript) on the NW.js wiki

Note that the starter project you linked to bundles its JavaScript up using browserify and loads it via a `<script>` tag. As a result that code is being run in the browser context, in which `document` is available.

If you're using `require()` directly to import your code, that's running in the Node context, in which `document` is not available. If you'd got any further you'd also have hit issues using React if it was imported with `require()`, as it detects whether or not it's being executed in a browser context and behaves accordingly.